# How to get gif working in android using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Before marking it as a duplicate please I want to make it clear that I haven't ejected my expo app.
I want gif file to work within the Android app but without ejecting that. It is working great in iOS though.
I saw many answers on StackOverflow and on GitHub too using fresco library but that requires the expo app to be ejected but I don't want to eject my app.

Is there any other hack to opt gif file in my android without making changes in the Android gradle file.

Comment: GIF and WebP are not supported by default on Android. [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#gif-and-webp-support-on-android)

Comment: @LonelyCpp Is there any way to achieve that without ejecting the app?

Comment: @RishavKumar you need to have android native folder to put in the gradle dependencies in the `app/build.gradle` so its necessary to eject the react-native app.

Comment: @RishavKumar why do you to avoid ejection?

Comment: @LonelyCpp I am somewhat new to react native and I dont know if I eject my app, will I again be able to write in JS again and use the expo library again?
Also If I eject my app the changes which I will make in my screens using javascript, will they be reflected in android and iOS folders also? 
I have read the documents but they are'nt very clear
Any help from your side is very much appreciated.

Comment: @RishavKumar the JS code will not be reflected into the native folders. The native folders are just to give you more capabilities with regards to platform, and once you want to eject any RN app you want to use expo too then you should consider [ExpoKit](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/expokit)